# How to know what Wordpress PHP file is making external requests?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, wordpress

My hosting provider is telling me that they are misusing my server, I want to know which of my 40 wordpress sites is doing bruteforce to other wordpress sites external to my server.

I scanned with clamav but found nothing.

How can I mitigate the attack?

Use debian 9, vestacp panel, nginx, php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

Look for outgoing connections:

> netstat -nputw

Maybe grep for .php

> netstat -nputw | grep .php

Also look in your uploads folder for a php file:

> find /path/to/uploads | grep .php